# Looking to take Quantity from a text input and use OnClick="location.href" to push information to new page

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

Currently I am using this to submit a quantity of 1 product to my cart page with a simple Onclick add to cart button.

```
<td class="data_cell dataFontColor">
                <label onClick="location.href='cart/?PartNo=#NPart#&Qty=1'">Add to 
Cart</label></td>
            <td class="data_cell dataFontColor">
                 <cfif IsDefined ("getPrice2.Price") AND getPrice2.Price eq "">
```

I am trying to implement a text box to submit any quantity the user wants, but on submit the page moves but nothing is added to cart. I know it's something wrong with the Qty= in the OnClick, but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<td class="data_cell dataFontColor">
            <td><input type="text" name="Qty" size="4" value= "Qty" maxlength="9"/></td>
            <td class="data_cell dataFontColor">
            <label onClick="location.href='shop/?PartNo=#NPart#&Qty=#Trim (Qty)#'">Add to 
Cart</label></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because you can't do what you're attempting using ColdFusion which processes the page server-side.  User typed inputs are processed client-side.

First, I would add an `id` attribute to your `input` tag.

```
<input type="text" id="Qty" name="Qty" size="4" value= "Qty" maxlength="9"/>
```

Once your `input` has an ID, now you can now extract the value client-side using JavaScript.

```
<label onClick="location.href='shop/?PartNo=#NPart#&Qty="+document.getElementById("Qty").value.trim()>Add to Cart</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am extremely new to CF and am  learning as I go. I'll give this method a try, and see what happens.

Comment: @MatthewW. No problem.  The "simplest" way to help you distinguish is this.  Variables that are processed to generate the html source are done using server-side code like ColdFusion.  Variables that are processed client-side are done using client-side code like JavaScript.  That's not a perfect description but an easy way for a beginner to understand.

Comment: Speaking of simplest, I think the simplest way to achieve your goal is with a straightforward html form.

Comment: @DanBracuk your answer is actually correct.  However, given that he already chose to go with an `onClick()` solution using url variables, I answered it based on his existing usage.  Perhaps you can provide your solution as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @user12031119 Thank you for the help. The reason I am using OnClick/ CF is because this is operating in a premade CF site that I am trying to fix. I tried implementing what you provided and it appears as though the OnClick itself doesn't work. Going through the Console isn't giving me a lead though. I thought it might be ending the OnClick too soon due to the " after Qty=, but trying to edit that didn't provide me anything either. I will keep trying to edit and if you have any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it, thank you again!

Comment: @MatthewW. It should work, but you have to keep in mind that the `id` needs to be unique.  That is, if there's another input on your page with `id="Qty"` on it, then my solution will not work.  However, if the `id` is unique on the page, it should work just fine.